# I want to take in a word such as "NAV" from the command line and use it as a command

Tags: console, char, nav, phrase

Im trying to create a text based adventure game. It prompts the user for a command NAV SHLD PHAS LRS SRS EXIT.

I could easily make the commands related to numbers and do it that way, but that is not as cool. I want my code to be able to recognize that one of these phrases has been entered in console and proceed from there.

```
printf("NAV   PHAS  LRS  SHLD   DOCK   EXIT  \n");
    printf("Command ? \n");
    scanf("%c", &command);
```

This is how I tried to get the code to work and needless to say it does not.
The Variable "command" is a declared as a char "char command;"

Thank you for any help you can give me i've hit quite a roadblock here :(